# How to get objects from generic ArrayList with Iterators?

Tags: java, iterator

I trying to create a class with an ArrayList attribute. I need to get the different objects using generics and iterators. The problem appears when i get objects from iterator. Here is code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class PruebaIterator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A<B> myList = new A<B>();

        myList.aad(new B());
        myList.aad(new B());

        myList.showList();


        A<C> myList2 = new A<C>();

        myList2.aad(new C());
        myList2.aad(new C());

        myList2.showList();     
    }
}

class A<T>{
    private ArrayList<T> list;

    public A(){
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void aad(T val){
        list.add(val);
    }

    public void showList(){
        Iterator it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            T obj = (T)it.next(); //Here: how to get different objects
            obj.showData();
        }
    }
}

class B{
    private String data;

    public B(){
        data = new String("B");
    }

    public void showData(){
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

class C{
    private String dat;

    public C(){
        dat = new String("C");
    }

    public void showData(){
        System.out.println(dat);
    }
}
```

I have tried it with cast but I have nothing. However, if I change T to B in only line commented, run for myList but not for myList2(I understand this). So, how to get objects from class B and C and calls showData method from both two classes?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [polymorphism](https://www.armedia.com/blog/instanceof-avoid-in-code/). You can introduce an interface. This interface will be implemented by every class that you want to use in your A class.

For example:

```java
interface Show {
    void showData();
}
```

After that you only need to change this:

```java
class B implements Show {
...
```

```java
class C implements Show {
...
```

```java
class A<T extends Show> {
...
```

And the method `showList` can be as it was. Or you can simplified it:

```java
public void showList() {
    list.forEach(obj -> obj.showData());
}
```

or even:

```java
public void showList() {
    list.forEach(Show::showData);
}
```

#### UPDATE

Using `class A<T extends Show> {` required less change in your code. You can replace it direct with interface. Then it would look like this:

```java
class A{
    private ArrayList<Show> list;

    public A(){
        list = new ArrayList<Show>();
    }

    public void aad(Show val){
        list.add(val);
    }

    public void showList(){
        list.forEach(Show::showData);
    }
}
```

And in `PruebaIterator` :

```java
...
A myList = new A();
...
A myList2 = new A();
...
```

Comment: Sintaxis `<T extends Interface`> is new to me, but this is the solution I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: I added other solution without  `<T extends Interface>`. It was easier for me to use it at first place as it requires less @ChenteInsane

Comment: Thank you. But I prefer the another solution. I need to use sintaxis <T>.

Answer (score 0):

instanceof operator need to be used in this case while getting data from generic list. So if T is of B type we can typecast in to B, if its if C type we can typecast it to C like below

```
public void showList(){
        Iterator it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            T obj = (T) it.next(); //Here: how to get different objects
            if(obj instanceof B) {
                B b = (B) obj;
                b.showData();
            }
            if(obj instanceof C) {
                C c = (C) obj;
                c.showData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. This is a partial solution, because I don't know the number of classes, but minimum there are five different type objects, new type classes are created continuously. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I prefer the solution base on polymorphism though.